# High replication datastore consistency across instances

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

A pretty simple question really. Are queries consistent across instances?

I understand that with the following query, I may miss some newly `put` entities.

```
messages = Message.all().filter('user =', current_user).fetch(20)
```

However, is it safe to assume that once an entities is returned from this query, it will always be returned by it *(ignoring the fact that it may not be in the first 20)*?

If so, does it extend to other queries of the same entity (using a different index)

```
messages = Message.all().filter('user =', current_user)
                        .filter('posted >', old_date) .fetch(20)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What instance you do an operation from has absolutely no effect on the result - all instances query the same set of datastore servers.

Once a new entity (or a modification to an entity) shows up in a query result, you can assume that it will do so for all future executions of that query. That does not imply that the entity will show up for *different* queries that should include it yet, though.

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case, best to be sure though ;)

Comment: @Nick What did you guys use to write the HRD? quantum physics !? ;-).  How can anyone write a sustainable model where he cannot trust at any give moment that the data the he sees is the most up to data? I guess its OK for MASSIVE search index, but for day to day data apps this is VERY problematic.

Comment: It's not quantum rocket surgery, it's one of caveats related to massive distributed systems. An event (such as datastore update) cannot happen everywhere at once, so there will be places which are notified later than others. The update will **eventually** reach all nodes in network and this is assumption upon which the consistency model is built upon.

Comment: @ShayErlichmen You can always get the latest copy of a record by doing a consistent get or working in a transaction. Note that outside a transaction, though, even with a strongly consistent database you can't guarantee you have the latest data - because the moment you get done fetching it, someone could modify it.